# Remote Web GUI for C++ application

Tags: c++, c, web-applications, embedded, iot

I have a Windows+Linux C++ application. I would like to show a (remote) control panel as a web application.

There are numerous embedded web servers available for C++ (Poco, civetweb, restinio, etc), but that is only the first building block of the solution.

I would also need to generate the HTML+CSS, the Javascript to open web sockets on the browser and build the UI, the websockets C/C++ code on the native side, and the synchronization of widgets between the browser app and the native app.

All of it will need to be packaged with the C++ app, so I would rather avoid the enormous number of dependencies of the typical Node app. It's also for a single user (or a few at most), it's not for building a large web site.

I have seen lots of old questions about this topic, but no obvious solution. All the desktop apps and the IoT devices (e.g. IP cameras, home automation hubs) that present a web interface must be doing some version of this. How do they do it effectively?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this embedded or iot related?

Comment: @RussSchultz because it would involve a web server embedded in the application, and because a lot of IoT devices would be doing something like this when they offer a web-based configuration panel.

Comment: Many IP cameras share the same embedded Linux code base. This lead to 1250 camera models and 185.000 cameras worldwide vulnerable to remote code execution. (Source: https://pierrekim.github.io/blog/2017-03-08-camera-goahead-0day.html) Please check https://cve.mitre.org/ for all the libraries you intend to use.

Comment: Small embedded devices (especially with internal SRAM < 256 KiB) avoid any dynamic generation of web content when possible, as it's expensive (in terms of both CPU/RAM required and development effort). Typically a static HTML page is served which includes a Javascript program to implement the dynamic parts of UI. Any actual logic behind the UI (e.g. accepting and processing POST requests) is often done in plain C. Having said that, I've also participated in a project where the web UI was dynamically generated using jim (an embedded Tcl interpreter) - but it was a rather complicated project.

Answer (score 0):

A complete blueprint for such a solution is given in

https://realtimelogic.com/articles/Modern-Approach-to-Embedding-a-Web-Server-in-a-Device

> In this article, we will look into how we can modernize embedded web based device management by using reactive programming techniques, not only for the user interface, but also for the complete solution, including changes propagated in real time from the device to all connected browsers. A modern reactive web based application is commonly assembled as a Single Page Application (SPA) and many tools facilitate reactive SPA development, including AngularJS, ReactJS, and Vue.js. We will move on to designing a reactive multiuser based solution for controlling shared resources in the device. The fully functional example we will present can be downloaded and loaded in your browser and run without having to install any software.

They are promoting the use of their commercial components for some subtasks in the solution architecture. Nevertheless, some of them have a free tier and others can be replaced with cost-/royalty-free alternatives.

Comment: Thanks! I think I had come across that page, not sure why I had dismissed it at the time. I will definitely have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

I have only tested this on Windows and I haven't tried it with an IoT but you can use Poco HTTP Server as your local webserver and a remote webserver for your database, remote management, and the GUI.

You must upload your backend scripts and frontend scripts to your remote server hosted somewhere on the internet and your frontend scripts must send ajax requests to your local server at 127:0.0.1:your_port, you can use vanilla JS or JQuery for this.

The local server will read the requests and send a response back which will also be processed by your frontend script.

Also you need to enable CORS on the local server otherwise you won't be able to send requests to the local server.

**Here's an example of a Poco HTTP Server:**
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/252827/Learning-Poco-A-Simple-HTTP-Server

**Here's an example of enabling CORS, reading POST fields, and creating responses:**

```
class MyRequestHandler : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler {
public:
    virtual void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& req, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& resp) {
        resp.setStatus(Poco::Net::HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK);
        resp.setContentType("application/json");

        resp.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        resp.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

        Poco::Net::HTMLForm form(req, req.stream());

        std::string fn, arg1, arg2, arg3;

        if (form.has("fn"))
            fn = form["fn"];

        if (form.has("arg1"))
            arg1 = form["arg1"];

        if (form.has("arg2"))
            arg2 = form["arg2"];

        if (form.has("arg3"))
            arg3 = form["arg3"];

        nlohmann::json respObj = nlohmann::json::object();
        respObj["result"] = true;

    
        if (Util::String::search(fn.c_str(), "SET_NATION"))
            UserData::bNation = (byte)std::stoi(arg1);

        else
        {
            respObj["result"] = false;
            respObj["msg"] = "Undefined function/argument";
        }

        std::ostream& out = resp.send();

        out << respObj.dump();

        out.flush();
    }
};
```

**Replace this code with your own search function, you might wanna use boyer moore algorithm for faster comparisons**

```
Util::String::search
```

**Ignore this code**

```
UserData::bNation = (byte)std::stoi(arg1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2c: Mongoose is a very capable embedable webserver that can be easily added to any cpp project:

https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose

https://mongoose.ws/

It is lightweight, runs on various platforms and doesn't need additional dependencies (IIRC).
Just check the License if it is suitable for you (Dual licensed, commercial use requires license).

Answer (score 0):

Try "jsVar" a library I put on github a few days ago. It is fresh new library but the code itself is old extracted from a production software. It's MIT licensed, light-weighted and does what you are asking for: it creates a webserver with websockets and some handling code on both sides. It supports wchar_t and depends only on openSSL (if SSL server is required).

Here is the ["link"](https://github.com/Marian-Vittek/jsvar) as it is not indexed by Google yet.